# AwsS3 unit test cases

Tags: scala, unit-testing, amazon-s3

I am trying to write unit test cases for  awazon s3 to upload files.I have used mokito. 
Following is my code for inserting files in S3:

```
  def insertingFilesInS3(path: String, file: File): Boolean = {
try {
  s3client.putObject(BUCKET_NAME, path, file)
  true
} catch {
  case ex: Exception => info(s"File storage failed for $path $file" + ex.printStackTrace()); false
}}
```

So far I have written:

```
 val s3: AmazonS3Client = mock[AmazonS3Client]("s3")
 val messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
  val bucket = "bucket"
  val keyName = "keyName"
  val file: File = mock[File]
  val expectedResult: PutObjectResult = mock[PutObjectResult]
  val objectmetadata: ObjectMetadata =mock[ObjectMetadata]
  "return true when inserting files in s3" in {
    when(s3.putObject(bucket, keyName, file).setMetadata(objectmetadata)).thenReturn(expectedResult)
    val result = S3Util.insertingFilesInS3(keyName, file)
    assert(!result)
  }
```

Assert statemnt is throwing exception and I'm getting false as result.
I am getting null pointer exception :

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.Mimetypes.getMimetype(Mimetypes.java:160)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.Mimetypes.getMimetype(Mimetypes.java:201)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1642)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1604)
    at s3Utility.S3Util$class.insertingFilesInS3(S3Util.scala:15)
    at s3Utility.S3Util$.insertingFilesInS3(S3Util.scala:52)
    at com.codesquad.test.S3UtilityTest.S3UtilTest$$anonfun$1.apply(S3UtilTest.scala:28)
    at com.codesquad.test.S3UtilityTest.S3UtilTest$$anonfun$1.apply(S3UtilTest.scala:20)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike$$anon$1.apply(WordSpecLike.scala:1078)
    at org.scalatest.TestSuite$class.withFixture(TestSuite.scala:196)
    at com.codesquad.test.S3UtilityTest.S3UtilTest.withFixture(S3UtilTest.scala:12)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike$class.invokeWithFixture$1(WordSpecLike.scala:1075)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(WordSpecLike.scala:1088)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(WordSpecLike.scala:1088)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestImpl(Engine.scala:289)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike$class.runTest(WordSpecLike.scala:1088)
    at com.codesquad.test.S3UtilityTest.S3UtilTest.org$scalatest$BeforeAndAfter$$super$runTest(S3UtilTest.scala:12)
    at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfter$class.runTest(BeforeAndAfter.scala:203)
    at com.codesquad.test.S3UtilityTest.S3UtilTest.runTest(S3UtilTest.scala:12)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(WordSpecLike.scala:1147)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(WordSpecLike.scala:1147)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:396)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:384)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:384)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:379)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsImpl(Engine.scala:461)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike$class.runTests(WordSpecLike.scala:1147)
    at com.codesquad.test.S3UtilityTest.S3UtilTest.runTests(S3UtilTest.scala:12)
    at org.scalatest.Suite$class.run(Suite.scala:1147)
    at com.codesquad.test.S3UtilityTest.S3UtilTest.org$scalatest$WordSpecLike$$super$run(S3UtilTest.scala:12)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(WordSpecLike.scala:1192)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(WordSpecLike.scala:1192)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runImpl(Engine.scala:521)
    at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike$class.run(WordSpecLike.scala:1192)
    at com.codesquad.test.S3UtilityTest.S3UtilTest.org$scalatest$BeforeAndAfter$$super$run(S3UtilTest.scala:12)
    at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfter$class.run(BeforeAndAfter.scala:258)
    at com.codesquad.test.S3UtilityTest.S3UtilTest.run(S3UtilTest.scala:12)
    at org.scalatest.tools.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.scala:45)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$1.apply(Runner.scala:1340)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call a method of a mocked object without stating what should it return. So first you need to state that. Also, you are chaining method calls to the s3 object. *setMetadata()* has no return value as its a Unit function, and you are asking it to return  *expectedResult* object of type PutObjectResult which will give you a compilation error. Instead, try the following.

```
  "return true when inserting files in s3" in {
    when(s3.putObject(bucket, keyName, file)).thenReturn(expectedResult)
    val result = S3Util.insertingFilesInS3(keyName, file)
    assert(!result)
  }
```